# Established connection to database but rendering a blank page

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am simply trying to display data from a table in my database.
For some reason, it keeps rendering a blank page. 
I have no training at all. SO I am sure my code looks like crap. But I can usually get it to work. I researched but all I could find were connection problems. I get a 'connected successfully' message but no data and no error message.

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost'; 
$db_user = 'user'; 
$db_pass = ''; 
$db_name = ''; 

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";



$query = "SELECT * FROM `my_table`";

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `my_table`");
if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
mssql_field_name($result,0);
//    print_r($row);
}
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you really setting a variable with one query statement (select * from...) but running a totally different query (show columns...) afterwards? Make sure that IS what you want. That said, there's two big errors on your code. First is you're opening the connection with mysqli_connect (which is ok) but attempting to run the query with mysql_query (which was deprecated and removed from PHP many versions ago). You should use mysqli_query.... The other, is mysqli_query expects two arguments. You should pass the connection handle and the query, not just the query

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php and try to follow the syntax for procedural style, which resembles your code more closely

Answer (score 0):

$db_name = ' ' ; is Null write Your Database Name

Answer (score 0):

You should first provide a `$db_name`, because it's currently blank

Answer (score 0):

$db_pass = ''; 
you need to provide your database name in here, else your application is literally trying to connect to nothing

Answer (score 0):

You might have to check $mysqli_connect, that the $db_name=''; is null...put your database name inside ''

Answer (score 0):

```
try like this.
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root',' ','databasename');
$query="Select * from my_table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);?>
<table>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>full_name</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["full_name"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your inputs.
The code above displays the table but the fields are empty
It is not pulling the data from the database.
The connection to the database is established but it is not pulling the data and displaying it.
I do not think it is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your database name and database password, then you can try like this :

```
$sql = "Select * from table_name";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
    // Fetch one and one row
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $response[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysqli_error();
    exit;
}
print_r($response);
```